# how to read azure app config values in C# startup.cs class in azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I have added key value pair in Azure app Configuration and trying to read it in Startup.cs class file.
Please suggest how to do that.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private static readonly string url= "*******************";
   
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        string connectionString=????? //How to get this value from Azure app config
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext, Context>(
            options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString));
       builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to split out configuration of your *configuration* from the registration of your application services. In other words, setup of Azure App Configuration should be done in `ConfigureAppConfiguration` while the registration of your `DbContext` should be done from the `Configure` method. This will allow you to access the `Configuration` property of the `FunctionsHostBuilderContext` in the `Configure` method to retrieve your connection string:

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private static readonly string url= "*******************";
   
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        // register AzureAppConfiguration only
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(url);
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = build.GetContext();
        var config = context.Configuration;

        string connectionString = config["AzureAppConfigKeyName"];
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext, Context>(
            options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString)
        );
    }
}
```

The value you pass to the indexer of the `config` object is going to depend on what you named your key in Azure App Configuration. Assuming you called it "DatabaseConnectionString" then that is exactly what you'll pass, ie: `config["DatabaseConnectionString"]`.

#### Prefixes

Azure App Configuration has a few features that can control how the key names are handled by the application, specifically the ability to "Trim Prefixes". You aren't using that here (since you are just passing the URL) but suppose you had keys in Azure App Configuration such as `MyFunction:DatabaseConnectionString`. By default you would access this using it's full name:

```cs
var cs1 = config["MyFunction:DatabaseConnectionString"];
// or
var cs2 = config.GetSection("MyFunction")["DatabaseConnectionString"];
```

You could however specify the long-form connection options. This would allow you to only select keys that begin with that prefix and optionally trim them off:

```cs
builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(s => 
{
    s.Connect(url, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    s.Select("MyFunction:*");
    s.TrimKeyPrefix("MyFunction:");
});
```

Which would now make your connection string available with a shorter key:

```cs
string connectionString = config["DatabaseConnectionString"];
```

This feature is especially useful if you have a lot of different settings in your Azure App Configuration instance and only want to pull in those specifically related to your application (labels can also be used for this purpose).

#### Azure App Config Connection - Environment Variables

Finally, a suggestion. Don't store the `url` or connection details of your Azure App Configuration instance hard-coded in your application. Make use of environment variables for this. "Application Settings" in Azure App Service/Azure Functions are automatically added as environment variables to your application.

**Before** `ConfigureAppConfiguration` has run, a default set of configuration sources has already been added to the context/builder. These include `host.json`, `appsettings.json`, `local.settings.json` (when running locally) and environment variables. A "better" way to configure your link to Azure App Configuration is to use this mechanism.

For example, you can add a FunctionApp Application Setting named `AzureAppConfigUrl` that contains this value:

[image: Application Settings]

*Locally* you'd add a corresponding entry to your local.settings.json file:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureAppConfigUrl": "https://your-configuration.azconfig.io"
  }
}
```

You'd then reference this value when configuring Azure App Configuration. Locally it will pull from the JSON file and when running in Azure it will read from the Application Settings (or rather, the environment variables):

```cs
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
   var context = build.GetContext();
   var url = context.Configuration["AzureAppConfigUrl"];
   builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigureAppConfiguration` method should be used exclusively to configure application's `IConfiguration` object. There is another dedicated method `Configure` which should be used to configure application itself (e.g. dependency injection).

Here is the simple example:

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .SetBasePath(context.ApplicationRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}

public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

    // use configuration object 
}
```

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, you can always fallback to get the value from environmental variables, since settings are added to `Environment`

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseConnectionString"))
```

Comment: I am trying to read values from azure app configuration, not from appsetting.json file

Comment: @ArshitSingh you can still load configuration data from Azure App configuration. This is just example of configuration from appsettings.json, the focus should be on `Configure` method and its usage.

Comment: I am able to read it another class with help of IConfiguration but how to do it in this same class ConfigureAppConfiguration method

Comment: you shouldn't do it there, configure Dependency Injection in `Configure` method

Answer (score 0):

The doc below walks you through how to use Azure App Configuration in Azure Functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp